# How to mount camera on wall with EPS insulation?

Tags: insulation, mounting, ip-camera

I need to mount a couple of outdoor cameras at my house.
Exterior wall layers are EPS, and behind it cement board. The electrician put some conduits where I told him I wanted the cameras.
Any special screws in order to safely mount?

Comment: Foam _outside_ cement board? What's the finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try TherMax fixings (no affiliation).

Cement board isn't listed as an substrate, but the dowels are able to hold in all building boards.

[image]
Image source: fischer group of companies